# VirtualEnv cannot import name wraps

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I'm trying to figure out why my Djagno wsgi script won't run. It runs fine under normal python but virtualenv produces the following stack trace:

```
(virtualenv)... [~]# python djangosites/test1.wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "djangosites/test1.wsgi", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
  File "/home/myofirst/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from threading import Lock
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 13, in <module>
    from functools import wraps
ImportError: cannot import name wraps
```

It looks like I need to have functools installed. I tried this via easy_install and now neither pip or easy_install will run, they both complain about missing `wraps`. What do I need to install/uninstall to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a new virtualenv as this one was broken. No problems now.

Comment: You should accept this answer in order to 'close' the question.